# Convert multi-line tab separated text to an Array Swift 4

Tags: arrays, xcode10, swift4.2

I need to read a text file and convert it to an array so it can be used to populate a tableView. Each key in a line of the array will go into a different label in the tableView cell.

The tab separated text data structure looks something like this but with 120 lines:
TextA TextB TextC TextD

"TextA" goes into labelA, "TextB" goes into labelB, "TextC" goes into labelC and so on.

I have some of this working. I can read the text file and separate it by lines. The part I'm having trouble with is separating each line by the tabs and getting it into the array with keys. The part inside the for loop is where I'm having trouble. I'm not sure if that is the best approach.

I think I can figure out how to parse the array into the tableview but I will probable meed help with that too.

Thanks for the help.

```
    var figureArray = [String]()

    let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(gTheCollection).appendingPathExtension("txt")

    do {
        let readText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let theLines = readText.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        let theCount = theLines.count - 1
        for i in 0...(theCount) {

            let figureData = theLines[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")

            figureArray.append(figureData[0])
            figureArray.append(figureData[1])
            figureArray.append(figureData[2])
            figureArray.append(figureData[3])
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? The line `let figureData = theLines[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes let figureData = theLines[i].components(separatedBy: "\t") does work.
It separates the sting at the tabs but it just makes the tabs commas.

If I print theLines I get:
["TextA\tTextB\tTextC\tTextD", "TextE\tTextF\tTextG\tTextH"]

If I print figureArray after the code runs, I get:
["TextA", "TextB", "TextC", "TextD", "TextE", "TextF", "TextG", "TextH"]

I think the problem is how I'm appending figureArray. Sorry, I'm having some trouble explaining the problem.

Comment: ["TextA", "TextB", ... , "TextH"] (comma separated values) is the format Swift uses when it prints arrays in the terminal, so it sounds to me like your code is actually doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this.

```
func buildTheDictionary() {
    let DocumentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(gTheCollection).appendingPathExtension("txt")

    figureArray = []

    do {
        let readText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let theLines = readText.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]

        for i in 1..<theLines.count {

            let figureData = theLines[i].components(separatedBy: "\t") as [String]

            figureDict["obrien"] = figureData[0] //"\(figureData[0])"
            figureDict["manuf"] = figureData[1] //"\(figureData[1])"
            figureDict["descript"] = figureData[2] //"\(figureData[2])"
            figureDict["notes"] = figureData[3] //"\(figureData[3])"

            figureArray.addObjects(from: [figureDict])
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "figureList_Cell", for: indexPath) as! FigureList_Cell

    let figures = figureArray[indexPath.row]

    theCell.obrienLabel.text = (((figures as AnyObject) .object(forKey: "obrien") ?? "") as! String)
    theCell.manufLabel.text = (((figures as AnyObject) .object(forKey: "manuf") ?? "") as! String)
    theCell.descriptionLabel.text = (((figures as AnyObject) .object(forKey: "descript") ?? "") as! String)
    theCell.notesLabel.text = (((figures as AnyObject) .object(forKey: "notes") ?? "") as! String)


    return theCell
}
```